# Set Excel solver to find a solution within a range?

Tags: excel, vba, range, solver

I am using solver to find a solution. I always know my solution is within a particular range. How can i set a solver (VBA) to use this range.Any idea?

This is my code, I just want add some range like min ="A34" Max="A45" and want solver to find solution between this range.

```
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("massfr").Value, _
  MaxMinVal:=1, _
  ValueOf:="0", _
  ByChange:=Range("pdvary").Value 
SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True 
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("massfr").Value, _
  MaxMinVal:=1, _
  ValueOf:="0", _
  ByChange:=Range("pdvary").Value
```

Comment: Give us more details.

Comment: Ok this is my code, i just want add some range like min ="A34" Max="A45" and want solver to find solution between this range. SolverOk SetCell:=Range("massfr").Value, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=Range("pdvary").Value
    SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
    SolverOk SetCell:=Range("massfr").Value, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=Range("pdvary").Value
    SolverSolve

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '.value' from your range.  I think it should look like this:

```
ByChange:=Range("pdvary")
```

Full code: (untested)

```
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("massfr"), _
  MaxMinVal:=1, _
  ValueOf:="0", _
  ByChange:=Range("pdvary") 
SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True 
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("massfr"), _
  MaxMinVal:=1, _
  ValueOf:="0", _
  ByChange:=Range("pdvary")
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839427.aspx) for more info.